# Search through my posts

Tags: support, android-app

Is there a way to search through my own posts on Android mobile app? Is there a search option in the app? I'm not seeing it.

Here is what I see:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open menu by swipe from the left border to the right.

> [image: menu]

Then select site where you want to search.

You could try `user:me` in the search line.

> [image: search]

Worth noting that it is only for questions. As far as I know you can't search through answers via android app.